# Higher dimensional delta-function from higher dimensional Gaussian

Tags: homework-and-exercises, mathematics, dirac-delta-distributions

Consider a higher dimensional (or rather multivariate) gaussian

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{(2\pi)^n \det{M}}}e^{-\frac{1}{2}x^TM^{-1}x}$$
where $M$ is some matrix. What limit of the above one must take to get some higher dimensional (or multivariate?) delta-function?

Comment: Would [math.se] be a better home for this question?

Comment: @Qmechanic Not sure. I mean whatever allows it to have better visibility.

Comment: Hi user44690. Whatever you do, please don't crosspost it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $1$-dimensional result we want to generalize is that $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi M}}e^{-Mx^2/2}$ is a nascent delta; in particular, it's of the form $\tfrac{1}{\epsilon}p\left(\tfrac{x}{\epsilon}\right)$ for $p$ a PDF, with $\epsilon=\sqrt{M}$. In $n$ dimensions, we take $M$ to be a symmetric positive-definite and hence diagonalizable matrix, and any basis that diagonalizes $M$ makes $f$ a product of $n$ PDFs $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi M_{ii}}}\exp\left(-\tfrac12M_{ii}x_i^2\right)$. The $M_{ii}\to0^+$ [distributional limit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Limit_of_distributions) of $f$ is $\prod_{i=1}^n\delta(\sqrt{M_{ii}}x)$ in the diagonalizing basis, so the basis-independent result is $\delta\left(\sqrt{M}x\right)$. Note the positive-definite choice of $\sqrt{M}$ [is unique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square_root_of_a_matrix#Positive_semidefinite_matrices).

Comment: Suppose you diagonalize via $M' = U^TMU$ where $M'$ is diagonal, then shouldn't the delta-function be $\delta(Ux)$?

Comment: @user44690 The argument needs to be proportional to $\sqrt{M}$ by dimensional analysis, power-counting etc.